# Show badge count on MenuItem of BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

As the title, I want to show badge count on MenuItem of BottomNavigationView. I have searched several ways but there is no one worked for me.

Please give me an direction to solve this problem. I will grateful any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073610/7254873

Answer (score 0):

**[BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)** is a **FrameLayout**. Put a **TextView** inside the BottomNavigationView for counting:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView android:id="@id/bottomMenu" style="@style/bottomMenu">
        <TextView android:id="@id/bottomMenuSelectionsNumber" style="@style/bottomMenuSelectionsNumber"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

And style them like this:

```
<style name="bottomMenu">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/toolbarHeight</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center|bottom</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorThird</item>
    <item name="itemBackground">@drawable/tabs_ripple</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@drawable/bottom_menu_item_color</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@drawable/bottom_menu_item_color</item>
    <item name="menu">@menu/bottom_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomMenuSelectionsNumber">
    <item name="android:text">@string/bottomMenuSelectionsNumber</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/appSecondFontSize</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/bottomMenuSelectionsNumberDim</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/bottomMenuSelectionsNumberDim</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right|bottom</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/bottomMenuSelectionsNumberMarginR</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/bottomMenuSelectionsNumberMarginB</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_menu_selections_number_bg</item>
</style>
```

And **bottom_menu_selections_number_bg**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/cornerRadius"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

While using bottom navigation view. its diffcult to include a badge. Bu there are easy ways to do so.
You can use this lib: [AHBottomNavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation).

Its an advanced version of bottom navigation. Code will go something like below.

```
bottomNavigation.setNotification(notification,bottomNavigation.getItemsCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Created sample project and shared in GITHub, Hope this helps

https://github.com/chandrahasan/BadgeView-Android/

```
 badgeIcon = (View) findViewById(R.id.badgeIcon);
 initBadge(this);

 private void initBadge(Context paramContext) {
        this.badgeCount = new BadgeView(paramContext);
        this.badgeCount.setTargetView(this.badgeIcon);
        this.badgeCount.setBadgeCount(count);
        this.badgeCount.setBadgeMargin(9);
 }
```

Comment: Is there any way to show badge with BottomNavigationView?

Comment: You can assign this Badge with any view component, like 
`this.badgeCount.setTargetView(this.badgeIcon);`