# How to display badge for a menuItem of BottomNavigationView of material library (version 1.1.0-alpha08)?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, material-components

I just want to add badge for a `menuItem` of `BottomNavigationView` in my app. I'm using `BottomNavigationView` of Material Components library(version 1.1.0-alpha08) since its the latest version released just 7 days ago from now I didn't found any tutorial for the same, Now because there are changes made in this version of `BottomNavigationView`'s showBadge method we cannot use that method.

I've tried calling `getBadge` and `getOrCreateBadge` method over instance of `BottomNavigationView`.

```java
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
if (bottomNavigationView.getBadge(3) == null) {
    audioPlayingCountBadge = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(3);
    audioPlayingCountBadge.setBackgroundColor(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    );
} else {
    audioPlayingCountBadge = bottomNavigationView.getBadge(3);
}
audioPlayingCountBadge.setVisible(true);
```

If anyone can provide solution for this problem in detail that would be very grateful to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- First migrate your project to androidX. [How to migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873)
- Include dependency in your `build.gradle`:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:version'`   [Get Version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)

- Your Base AppLevel theme should use `Material Component Theme` like:

**Your App Level Theme**

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Activity code:**

```
val menuItemId: Int = btm_nav.menu.getItem(0).itemId //0 menu item index.
badgeDrawable = btm_nav.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId)
badgeDrawable.isVisible = true
badgeDrawable.number = 10

badgeDrawable.badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_END    //badge gravity
//BadgeDrawable.TOP_START
//BadgeDrawable.BOTTOM_END
//BadgeDrawable.BOTTOM_START

badgeDrawable.isVisible = false   //hide badge
badgeDrawable.clearNumber()
```

**XML layout:**

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/btm_nav"
      style="@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

Comment: it worked by changing data type of variable menuItemId to int. Thanks @SumitShukla

Comment: holy crap thank you, I was wondering what happened to showBadge when I upgraded from 1.1.0alpha07

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, showing dot notification is really simple just need to add 1 line.

`bottomNavigationView=findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BOTTOM_NAVIGATION_LAYOUT_ID);`

To Show dot over bottom navigation item just use this
`bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.YOUR_NAV_ITEM_ID).setVisible(true);`

and
To Hide dot over bottom nav item use this line
`bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.YOUR_NAV_ITEM_ID).setVisible(false);`

You can also set numbers if you want just go through the latest document to read about it.

Comment: Hi . I am being trying to do the same. But studio is not unable to reference  getOrCreateBadge methods. can you help me with this

Comment: Have you initilized bottom navigation because it would give option over it.?

Comment: Yes I did. But unable to find badgeDrawable class also in android studio

Comment: Please add Gradle dependency  ```implementation 'com.google.android.matetial.matetial.1.2.1' ```

Comment: using 1.4.0 . but still no luck

Comment: then  seems everything fine, it may ask to import its class

Comment: unable to find BadgeDrawable class. What things should I consider. I mean what could be the reason

Comment: you should have created menu items for bottom navigation. If you have but still this is the case then I think you should consider raising separate question specific to your issue.

Comment: I am adding menu items at runtime

Comment: raise a proper question how you are doing and what issue you facing

Comment: done here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283625/adding-badges-to-bottom-navigation-and-not-able-to-reference-the-getorcreatebadg