# Adding badges to Bottom navigation and not able to reference the getOrCreateBadge

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, badge

I am trying to add badges in bottom navigation but the problem is getOrCreateBadge is not getting referenced. I am unable to access this method.

Error : Unresolved reference: getOrCreateBadge

```
 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/bnv_nav"
       app:defaultNavHost="true"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/bnv_nav"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minHeight="@dimen/dp56"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color"
       app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_color" />
```

Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
       <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:targetApi="27">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
   </style>
```

I am adding menu item during run time.

Things which I have already tried :

1. Adding menu items from xml itself : still no effect
2. Changing theme to material theme : still same issue
3. Created a separate project with bottom navigation activity : No issue in that project if I add badges. I have changed it's theme too to my app theme i.e. App compat still badges are working fine in that project.
4. Initially dependency was not added of android material and I was able to use bottom navigation bar. But as I faced problem while adding badges so I have added dependency externally and made sure to put latest version also but still at the end facing the same issue. Unable to add badges in bottom navigation.

I know it's something very basic but if somebody could point it out that it would be a great help already stuck with this issue from past two days. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0' . Make sure you delete the builds folder before gradle sync and rebuild.

Comment: I have checked I was able to figure out the issue as app is pointing to material design 1.0.0(post migration) due to which I am unable to use badges. Can you suggest me any workaround from which I can point bottom navigation component to latest material design. and rest of the components are unimpacted(i e can use app compat).

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'  Any problem using v 1.3.0?

Comment: Something like this may help <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
 />